# Insert a string mid line in perl

Tags: regex, perl

So I'm trying to figure out how to append a string to the end of a string that occurs mid-line within a file and has a variable in between. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Sample string

```
depends = object_OBJA object_OBJB place_PLACEA place_PLACEB
```

what i want to return

```
depends = object_OBJA object_OBJB place_PLACEA[RANGE] place_PLACEB[RANGE]
```

I've tried using a regular expression but i can't seem to get it to skip the PLACEA section.

example of something I've tried. I just can't seem to figure out how to preserve the PLACEA without just doing a direct replacement. Ideally I would be able to have it find the place, skip the _PLACEA and append the [RANGE] after, but it seems to just replace the entirety of the string.

```
perl -p -e 's/place.+?/[$"RANGE"]/ge' test.ctl
```

Comment: Show us (code) what you have tried so far.

Comment: @m0skit0, sometimes i wish my brain had the patience to comment as you did rather than jumping to writing an answer...  _Teach a man to fish..._

Comment: perl -p -e 's/place.+?/[$"RANGE"]/ge' test.ctl

example of something I've tried. I just can't seem to figure out how to preserve the PLACEA without just doing a direct replacement. Ideally I would be able to have it find the place, skip the _PLACEA and append the [RANGE] after, but it seems to just replace the entirety of the string.

Comment: Why perl?  You seem to be doing it on the command line, so use sed: try `sed 's/place[^ ]\+/&["RANGE"]/g' test.ctl`

Comment: I was just testing it on the command line, It will eventually live within some of our perl scripts, but i guess i could run it via a `` or system() within the perl script.

Comment: BY definition, you can't append something in the middle. You could insert it though.

Comment: Ah.  Well then.  try using $& to reference the matched string. `perl -p -e 's/place[^ ]+/$&[$"RANGE"]/ge' test.ctl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\K` regex operator might be interesting for you: It “forgets” that it matched the previous pattern. This is very useful for substitutions, as we can assert that a certain pattern matched, but don't actually replace the matched text. This is more convenient than look-around assertions.

This would make your substitution:

```
s{ place_\w+ \K }
 {[RANGE]}xg;
```

A test:

```
my $string   = "depends = object_OBJA object_OBJB place_PLACEA place_PLACEB";
my $expected = "depends = object_OBJA object_OBJB place_PLACEA[RANGE] place_PLACEB[RANGE]";

use Test::More;
(my $altered = $string) =~ s{ place_\w+ \K }{[RANGE]}xg;
ok $altered eq $expected, "correct substitution";
```

Notes:

- I use `\w+` to match the rest of the `place_` word. This may or may not do what you want. You have to think about where *exactly* the `[RANGE]` is to be inserted.
- Using `\K` is potentially more performant than using captures.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
$line =~ s/^(depends = object_OBJA object_OBJB place_PLACEA) (place_PLACEB)$/$1\[RANGE] $2\[RANGE]/
```

Assuming you wanted to match the literal string you put above.

*Untested*

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'depends = object_OBJA object_OBJB place_PLACEA place_PLACEB';
$s =~ s/(place_PLACE.)/${1}[RANGE]/g;

say $s;
```

Output:

```
depends = object_OBJA object_OBJB place_PLACEA[RANGE] place_PLACEB[RANGE]
```